# How to setup sentry with docker

Tags: docker, sentry

I have found the [official sentry image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/sentry/) in dockerhub. But the document is incomplete and I can't setup the environment step by step.

We have to setup the database container first but none of them tell how to setup it at first. Specifically I don't know what are the username and password that sentry will use.

And I also get the following error when I run the sentry container:

```
sudo docker run --name some-sentry --link some-mysql:mysql -d sentry
e888fcf2976a9ce90f80b28bb4c822c07f7e0235e3980e2a33ea7ddeb0ff18ce

sudo docker logs some-sentry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sentry", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sentry==6.4.4', 'console_scripts', 'sentry')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/utils/runner.py", line 310, in main
    initializer=initialize_app,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 167, in run_app
    configure_app(config_path=config_path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 89, in configure_app
    raise ValueError("Configuration file does not exist at %r" % (config_path,))
ValueError: Configuration file does not exist at '/.sentry/sentry.conf.py'
```

Comment: Try the steps and ask a question when you get stuck

Comment: I got stuck when I have tried the official image. Here's the [related issue](https://github.com/docker-library/sentry/issues/3). My problem is not knowing how to setup up database container before running sentry.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/ has a deprecation notice.

Answer (score 8):

### UPDATE circa version 21

They don't seem to want to build the official image for us any more as per the deprecation notice on Docker Hub. However, good news, in https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/#getting-started

- They supply an install script
- There is an official [docker-compose](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/21.9.0/docker-compose.yml) included

Seems Kafka and Zookeeper are now required too. Follow the docs to stay up to date.

---

This is a moving target. I suggest checking https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/ for updates as their documentation is pretty good.

Circa version 8 you can easily convert those instructions to use `docker-compose`

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.7
    networks:
    - sentry-net

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.1
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER:sentry
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:sentry
    # volumes:
    # - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    networks:
    - sentry-net

  sentry:
    image: sentry:${SENTRY_TAG}
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgres
    environment:
    - SENTRY_REDIS_HOST=redis
    - SENTRY_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET}
    - SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
    ports:
    - 9000:9000
    networks:
    - sentry-net

  sentry_celery_beat:
    image: sentry:${SENTRY_TAG}
    depends_on:
    - sentry
    environment:
    - SENTRY_REDIS_HOST=redis
    - SENTRY_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET}
    - SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
    command: "sentry run cron"
    networks:
    - sentry-net

  sentry_celery_worker:
    image: sentry:${SENTRY_TAG}
    depends_on:
    - sentry
    environment:
    - SENTRY_REDIS_HOST=redis
    - SENTRY_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET}
    - SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
    command: "sentry run worker"
    networks:
    - sentry-net

networks:
  sentry-net:
```

#### .env

```
SENTRY_TAG=8.10.0
```

Run `docker run --rm sentry:8.10.0 config generate-secret-key` and add the secret

#### .env updated

```
SENTRY_TAG=8.10.0
SECRET=somelongsecretgeneratedbythetool
```

First boot:

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
docker-compose up -d redis
docker-compose run sentry sentry upgrade
```

Full boot

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Debug

```
docker-compose ps
docker-compose logs --tail=10
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/ has a deprecation notice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [sentry.conf.py](https://github.com/docker-library/sentry/blob/master/sentry.conf.py) file that is part of the official sentry docker image. It gets a bunch of properties from the environment e.g. SENTRY_DB_NAME, SENTRY_DB_USER. Below is an excerpt from the file.

```
os.getenv('SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD')
or os.getenv('MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD')
or os.getenv('MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD')
```

So as for your question about how to sepcify database password it must be set in environment variables. You can do this by running:

```
sudo docker run --name some-sentry --link some-mysql:mysql \
    -e SENTRY_DB_USER=XXX                                  \
    -e SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD=XXX                              \
    -d sentry
```

As for your issue with the exception you seem to be missing a config file `Configuration file does not exist at '/.sentry/sentry.conf.py'` That file is copied to /home/user/.sentry/sentry.conf.py inside the container. I am not sure why your sentry install is looking for it at /.sentry/sentry.conf.py. There may be an environment variable or a setting that controls this or this may just be a bug in the container.

Comment: Thanks @usman for replying. It seems I should setup `-e SENTRY_DB_USER=XXX` and `-e SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD=XXX` like what you said. And I don't need to care about sentry.conf.py, right?

Comment: The config file references the environment variables so you still need to care.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me https://github.com/slafs/sentry-docker and we don't have to setup database or others. I will learn more about the configuration in detail later.

Answer (score 1):

Here my docker compose yml, with official image from https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/:

https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/270f4ef3abd41e1490c1

Run:

```
docker-compose -p sw up -d
docker exec -ti sw_sentry_1 sentry upgrade
```

Thats it!

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/ has a deprecation notice.